# How can I solve this problem of black screen on my JavaFx Mobile application?

Tags: android, javafx, gluon

I am running Gluon JavaFx sample project of Single View. An android apk file is successful  created but when I install an apk file to my android device running android 10, black screen appears and stay there forever. I have tried to solve the problem from different suggestions given to different kind of questions similar to mine, but problem still exist. I am using Eclipse IDE 2018-09, JDK 8

below is my gradle.build file. where am I making mistakes ? I need your help please.

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.18'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3" 
        minSdkVersion = 16 
        compileSdkVersion = 29 
        targetSdkVersion = 29 
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
      android { 
     dexOptions { 
          javaMaxHeapSize '1g' 
     }
  }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: JFXMobile plugin is EOL and you are running into this issue: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/issues/38 (hint, there is a workaround...). However, the new GluonFX plugin (JDK 11+) works fine on Android 10. See https://docs.gluonhq.com or https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples

Comment: Thanks so much @Jose Pereda, at least I know what causing this error. Let me shift to Java 11+ . Have a good day.